# SwiftUI on MacOS. - Opening a new Window

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, appkit

In my MacOS SwiftUI App I want to display some views in new Windows. The calls shall be possible from several parts of the code so I decided, do implement it as a static func of as special struct like this.
Works fine - there is something to be said against it?

```
struct Appwindows {
  
  static func newWindow(forSpecialView view: SpecialView, title: String = "new Window")
 { let newWindow = newWindowInternal(title: title)!
   
    newWindow.contentView = NSHostingView(rootView: view)
 }
  
  private static func newWindowInternal(title: String = "new Window") -> NSWindow!
 { var newWindow: NSWindow!
   newWindow = NSWindow(
     contentRect: NSRect(x: 20, y: 20, width: 680, height: 600),
     styleMask: [.titled, .closable, .miniaturizable, .resizable, .fullSizeContentView],
     backing: .buffered,
     defer: false)
     newWindow.center()
     newWindow.isReleasedWhenClosed = false
     newWindow.title = title
     newWindow.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
     return newWindow
 }
}
```

Is there a way to make it more generic, so that any kind of views could be passed to the func?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Make your function generic and add view constraint.

```
static func newWindow<Content: View>(forSpecialView view: Content, title: String = "new Window") { // <-- Here
```

---

Another good and easy solution is to use `View` extension.

```
extension View {
    private func newWindowInternal(with title: String) -> NSWindow {
        let window = NSWindow(
            contentRect: NSRect(x: 20, y: 20, width: 680, height: 600),
            styleMask: [.titled, .closable, .miniaturizable, .resizable, .fullSizeContentView],
            backing: .buffered,
            defer: false)
        window.center()
        window.isReleasedWhenClosed = false
        window.title = title
        window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
        return window
    }
    
    func openNewWindow(with title: String = "new Window") {
        self.newWindowInternal(with: title).contentView = NSHostingView(rootView: self)
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            ContentViewNewWindow().openNewWindow()
        }) {
            Text("Open New Window")
        }
    }
}
```